# Selector for list view

Tags: android, xml, list, android-layout, selector

I have a selector for different states of the list view. I have selected a grey colour for the background but its not working ,pressed state is working fine but my list view background is still white, and when I select the list item its colour changes to grey which I have chosen for the background and the background is still white.
Please help ,Sorry for the silly question as I am new to android.
My list view is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent" 

   android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator">


  <ListView
      android:id="@android:id/list"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:divider="#b5b5b5"
      android:dividerHeight="1dp"
      android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector">

  </ListView>

        </FrameLayout>
```

Selector xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
     android:state_selected="false"
        android:state_pressed="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/gradient_bg" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/gradient_bg_hover" />
    <item android:state_selected="true"
     android:state_pressed="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/gradient_bg_hover" />
</selector>
```

pressed_state xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
  <gradient
      android:startColor="#78DDFF"
      android:centerColor="#16cedb"
      android:endColor="#09adb9"
      android:angle="270" />
</shape>
```

background xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
  <gradient
      android:startColor="#D5DDE0"
      android:centerColor="#e7e7e8"
      android:endColor="#CFCFCF"
      android:angle="270" />
</shape>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply your selector to the ListView item, I mean the viewgroup of the row.xml or whatever name you have defined for the listview item.